# Solving a double integral in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to solve this integral:

$M = \rho h \int_0^a \int_0^b N^2 \ dx dy$

where $N$ is defined as:

$N = sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\eta +\dfrac{3\pi}{4}\right)sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\eta +\dfrac{3\pi}{4}\right)sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\psi +\dfrac{3\pi}{4}\right)sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\psi +\dfrac{3\pi}{4}\right)$

where $\eta = y/b$ and $\psi = x/a$ (change of variable)

Therefore the integral becomes:

$M = \rho h a b \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \biggl[sin^2\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\eta +\dfrac{3\pi}{4}\right)sin^2\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\psi +\dfrac{3\pi}{4}\right) \biggr]^2 \ d\eta d\psi$

To solve it I used the Matlab function `trapz()` in this way:

```
eta = 0:0.01:1; 
psi = 0:0.01:1;
rho = 2770; h = 0.0012; a = 0.127; b = 0.0508;
fun = rho*h*a*b.*(sin(pi/4.*psi+3*pi/4).*sin(pi/4.*psi+3*pi/4) ...
      .*sin(pi/4.*eta+3*pi/4).*sin(pi/4.*eta+3*pi/4)).^2;
M = trapz(fun);
```

$M = 0.0175$

But if I set

```
eta = 0:0.001:1; 
psi = 0:0.001:1;
```

then $M = 0.1754$

What am I doing wrong?

I also tried using the `quad2d()` function:

```
fun = @(eta,psi)  rho*h*a*b.*(sin(pi/4.*psi+3*pi/4).*sin(pi/4.*psi+3*pi/4) ...
      .*sin(pi/4.*eta+3*pi/4).*sin(pi/4.*eta+3*pi/4)).^2;
M = quad2d(fun,0,1,0,1);
```

But this time $M = 6.8920\times10^{-5}$

Comment: What is your actual question? Is there a reason you wan to use `trapz` instead of `integral2` or `quad2d`? `trapz` performs 1-D numerical integration, so you'll need to apply it more than once in your case – see [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html#buakefe-1_1).

Comment: The main problem is that I do not know how to do it. First I tried with trapz() but I felt it was not the right method, therefore I tried with quad2d().

Comment: Anyway I do not understand why the value of the integral using trapz() changes of one order of magnitude when I change the $d\eta$ and the $d\psi$

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\Delta \eta$ and $\Delta \psi$

Comment: I tried the code written in the documentation and I obtained the same result given by quad2d . I should look at the online documentation more often, the help doc of my matlab version is not so complete

Comment: I'm not surprised. You should probably use `integral2` instead of `quad2d` unless you have an older version of Matlab. You should be able to get the full documentation for any function for your version by typing, e.g., `doc trapz` in the command window. Fell free to answer and accept your own question if you think you've solved this or do you still not understand why your original `trapz` approach is wrong?

Comment: I got it thanks :) Actually I feel so silly to have tried integrating a 2D function using the `trapz` with a 1D syntax XD Anyway, I'll write a proper answer, just in case someone else is going to make my same mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the function to be integrated is dependent on 2 parameters: $\eta$ and $\psi$, it has to be integrated as a 2D function in this way:

```
x = 0:0.001:1;
y = x;
[eta,csi] = meshgrid(x,y);
fun = rho*h*a*b.*(sin(pi/4.*csi+3*pi/4).*...
...sin(pi/4.*csi+3*pi/4).*sin(pi/4.*eta+3*pi/4).*sin(pi/4.*eta+3*pi/4)).^2;
M = trapz(y,trapz(x,fun,2));
```

and this approach gives the same result obtained using the `quad2d` function.

```
fun = @(eta,psi)  rho*h*a*b.*(sin(pi/4.*psi+3*pi/4).*sin(pi/4.*psi+3*pi/4).*...
...sin(pi/4.*eta+3*pi/4).*sin(pi/4.*eta+3*pi/4)).^2;
M = quad2d(fun,0,1,0,1);
```

The main difference between the 2 methods is that in the `quad2d` the function to be integrated has to be defined as an function of the 2 parameters (in this case it has been defined as a `function_handle`).

Answer (score 2):

Your function $N$ is separable and the limits of integration are constants so this can easily be computed as the product of two one dimensional integrals. In fact those integrals are identical so it is just the square of a 1d integral.

\begin{align}
M &= \rho h a b \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left[sin^2\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\eta +\dfrac{3\pi}{4}\right)sin^2\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\psi +\dfrac{3\pi}{4}\right) \right]^2 \ d\eta d\psi\\
&= \rho h a b \int_0^1 sin^4\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\eta +\dfrac{3\pi}{4}\right) d\eta
\int_0^1 sin^4\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\psi +\dfrac{3\pi}{4}\right) d\psi\\
&= \rho h a b \left[\int_0^1 sin^4\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\eta +\dfrac{3\pi}{4}\right) d\eta\right]^2
\end{align}

This integral can be done analytically (I used [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+sin%5E4%28+pi%2F4*%28x%2B3%29+%29+from+0+to+1)), giving
$$
M = \rho h a b \left( \dfrac{3}{8}-\dfrac{1}{\pi} \right)^2\approx 6.8920\times10^{-5}
$$
if you use $\rho = 2770$, $h = 0.0012$, $a = 0.127$, $b = 0.0508$.

In general, if the function is separable but the integral can't be solved analytically it will be much more efficient to compute the product of two one-dimensional integrals than to directly compute the two-dimensional integral.

Answer (score 0):

The symbolic solution is direct in *Mathematica*:

```
\[Rho] h a b Integrate[Sin[\[Eta] \[Pi]/4 + 3 \[Pi]/4]^4  Sin[\[Psi] \[Pi]/4 + 3 \[Pi]/4]^4, {\[Eta], 0, 1}, {\[Psi], 0, 1}]
```

$\frac{(8-3 \pi )^2 a b h \rho }{64 \pi ^2}$